# AngularJS Typescript Directive

Tags: angularjs, typescript, directive

Having problems creating nested directive using Typescript. I can do it in simple AngularJs: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/UruTqEdMnqNT5wjxcQNC?p=preview ,

but using TypeScript it gives me **"No controller"** error message.

```
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/AngularJs/Typings/angular.d.ts" />

export class directiveA {
    public static $inject: Array<string> = [];
    constructor() {
        var directive: ng.IDirective = {};
        directive.priority = 0; 
        directive.restrict = "A";
        directive.scope = {};
        directive.transclude = true;
        directive.templateUrl = "otherTemplate.html";
        directive.replace = true;
        directive.controller = function ($scope, $element) {
            this.flip = function () {
                $element.toggleClass("flipped");
             }
        }
        directive.replace = true;

        return directive;
    }
} 


export class directiveB{
    public static $inject: Array<string> = [];
    constructor() {
        var directive: ng.IDirective = {};
        directive.require = "^directiveA";
        directive.priority = 1;
        directive.restrict = "A";
        directive.scope = {
            simplrSide : "@"
        };
        directive.transclude = true;
        directive.templateUrl = "templeUrl.html";
        directive.link = function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, simplrEditable) {
            scope.flip = function () {
                simplrEditable.flip();
            }
        }
        directive.replace = true;
        return directive;
    }
}
```

I dont know if its relevant, but i am using AMD Require.JS  for script load

Comment: I am assuming you are registering these. See my updated answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not related to Typescript, but to AngularJS Directives. 
Changing **templateUrl** to **template** and using inline code, helps to resolve the errors. It's AngularJS Issue, more on that: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1903
Hope they will fix this in the future!

```
export class directiveA {
    public static $inject: Array<string> = [];
    constructor() {
        var directive: ng.IDirective = {};
        directive.priority = 0; 
        directive.restrict = "A";
        directive.scope = {};
        directive.transclude = true;
        directive.template = "<div>Your content</div>";
        directive.replace = true;
        directive.controller = function ($scope, $element) {
            this.flip = function () {
               //Some func
             }
        }
        directive.replace = true;

        return directive;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you add a directive, declared in this way, to an Angular module?

Comment: `this.app.directive("myDirective", () => new directiveA());`

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you are registering these as :

```
import mod = require('yourfile')
youmodule.directive('directiveA',mod.directiveA);
youmodule.directive('directiveB',mod.directiveB);
```

That should work as long as your html looks like:

```
<div directiveA>
  <div directiveB>
  </div>
</div>
```

A couple of notes beyond that:

**Use functions for your directive definitions.**

This is because directives (unlike controllers) are called without the `new` operator. So if you have something like:

```
class Test{
    foo = "EAC";
    constructor(){
        var directive:any = {}; 
        directive.restrict = this.foo;
    }
}
```

It compiles to **incorrect** javascript. As the function Test is called without the new operator and that means that `this` refers to `window` and not an instance of the class. So you can't use anything defined outside the constructor anyways. I recommend something like:

```
function foo():ng.IDirective{
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC';    
    }
}
```

This way typescript will *help* you write correct javascript for angular instead of point you in the wrong way. *I will make a video about this at some point*

**Use classes for your controller**
Controllers inside of directives are also called with the new operator. Same as controllers outside : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E Again let typescript help you with the meaning of `this` inside the controller definition. Plus you can use the *type* for the controller in the child directive something like (for typesafety and inference):

```
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, simplrEditable:YourControllerClass)
```

**For injection into directive functions**
I still use $inject. I have the following interface definition :

```
interface Function{
    $inject:string[]
}
```

This means you can do :

```
foo.$inject = ['$compile']; // e.g
```

Comment: The way that i use directive lets me use injection, and i return an object when the function is called, so putting it into a function, would make me inject Injectables somewere else, where i define the directive. And this solution still dosint work, if the page contenct is taken from cache.

Comment: added a note about injection into functions :)

Comment: When registering the directive first letter of string identitier MUST BE LOWERCASE. This got me stuck for a little bit thinking I could follow C# convention on it, hope it helps someone.

Comment: @parliament follow the js convention when in html ;). PS reason: html is case insensitive => directive 'fooBar' is used as 'foo-bar' and therefore 'Foo' is not usable as '-foo' is weird on its own

Answer (score 2):

With my solution you can both use a TS class and not having to worry about a factory and repeat what you need injected.

```
module YourApp.Common.Directives {

    class SearchInputController {
        public query: string;

        constructor(private $location: ng.ILocationService) {
        }

        doSearch(): void {
            this.$location.url(`/search?q=${this.query}`);
            this.query = '';
        }
    }

    export function SearchInputDirective($location: ng.ILocationService): ng.IDirective {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'common/directives/searchInput/SearchInputDirective.html',
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            controllerAs: 'SearchInputController',
            bindToController: {
                'query': '@'
            },
            controller: (): any => new SearchInputController($location)
        };
    }

    SearchInputDirective.$inject = ['$location'];
}
```

To register:

```
angular.module('common', [])
    .directive('searchInput', YourApp.Common.Directives.SearchInputDirective);
```

And the HTML to see the whole picture (templateUrl):

```
<form ng-submit="SearchInputController.doSearch()">
    <input type="search" ng-model="SearchInputController.query">
</form>
```

Comment: This example works with `$location` but fails with `$scope`. I get an `Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- myDirective`

Comment: To fix this, I registered my controller in my directives module and specified `controller: 'MyDirectiveController'` in my directive.

Comment: Actually, here's [an even better method](http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/writing-cleaner-angularjs-with-typescript-and-controlleras/) (scroll down to directives/to-do-list.ts)

Answer (score 1):

a simple way to write directive in ts
I think can work with nested directive as well

```
class D{
    static foo(){
        return {
                restrict:'A',
                template:'<div>Here I am to save the day</div>',
                replace: true
            }
    }
}


/// <reference path="./angular.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="./directive.ts"/>
class MyApp{
    public app:AngularModule;
    constructor(){
          this.app = angular.module('myApp', []);
          this.app.directive ('superman',() => {
                return D.foo();
            } 
          );
    }
}
new MyApp();

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Directive</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-app="myApp">
            <div data-superman></div>  
        </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="./directive.js"></script>
    <script src="./appDirective.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```